# DevExtreme React - prevent rendering widged with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, devextreme

I am developing an app in React.js based on **DevExtreme** library. I need to perform some basic actions on DevExtreme widgets (NumberInput, TextInput, Button) - all of them contains method onClick or onValueChanged that should easly give me event object with whose I can do what I want. 
I am able to console their values on runtime but it is almost impossible to save their values into some hook:
 
```

```

```
const handleInput = e => {
 setValue(e.value); //always causes re-render
}
```

When I'm clicking on this button then parent component (some DevExtreme widged) performs rerender and appears imidiatetly after few seconds.

My question is - is there a way to prevent re-rendering parent component or get event object and save it to the state without re-rendering?

Comment: calling the setter function of a `useState` effect will always cause a re-render (unless the value does not change). you can check for changes to that state value in a `useEffect`. if you need a value that won't cause a re-render when it changes, use `useRef`. also you'll want to wrap that `handleInput` in a `useCallback` so it's not recreated every render, thus causing re-renders in components that accept it as a prop.

Comment: Alright I am pulling out data through useRef - I've got data what I wanted. But despite of this I also want to inject them into JSX to display values to the user. How can I create and save state to perform this outside of my handleInput function?
I've used to do this using smth like this setValue(value) where value is updated and it can be dynamically updated to the screen.

Comment: That's what useState is for.

Comment: So why this code keeps rerendering all component with dissapear: 
 const [nazwaValue, setNazwaValue] = useState(""); 

  const testHandleInput = useCallback(() => {
    return {
      showClearButton: true,
      value: nazwaValue,
      onValueChanged: (e) => {
        setNazwaValue(e.value);
      }
    };
  });

I am aware that always when we call setState/useState it causes update of state component that cause re-render - but here is hapening smth strange - input dissapear, all component dissapear and is going back again with empty inputs